# SFCC pipeline documentation

Tags: commerce-cloud, pipelines, b2c

I have found a pipeline documentation URL but does not open to me. does anyone know how I can read SFCC pipeline's basics? PLEASE suggest documentation for sfcc b2c pipeline version's documentntion
HERE IS THE URL THAT DOES NOT OPEN TO ME.
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/WorkingwithPipelines.html?cp=0_5_6

Comment: Are you looking for this documentation URL : https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FLegacyDevDoc%2FComparingPipelinesAndControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is pipeline basic information:

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FOCAPI%2Fcurrent%2Fshop%2FDocuments%2FOrder.html&anchor=id-2029169293